# How get shell out put in python 2.6 as line by line and conditionally check lines

Tags: python, linux, python-2.6

Could you please someone help me,I have get below output to variable and read their some information and store it to data base. Seems it take as single line, I want to divide to lines and print line by line.

OUTPUT of the command

```
kafka-mirror              Running (9)  on frun4316                                                             TIME            PID          Num.Streams
=======================================================================================================================================================
billing_-mainframe_-db2prod_-topic                                                                               Mar08           565
snap_-arep_-b2bowner_-topic,snap_-report_-b2bowner_-topic,snap_-arep_-isnapownera_-topic,snap_-report_-isnapownera_-topic Mar08           1024
meds_-mlinterview_-hiss_-topic,meds_-mlinterview_-dbo_-topic                                                     Mar08           1902
insite_-c1reppd_-insiteownera_-topic,insite_-cireprod_-insiteowner_-topic                                        Mar15           19386
atlas_-clmprgg_-geico_claimcenter_-topic                                                                         Mar15           22222            2
ecams_-ecamsdatastore_-ecamsmain_-topic                                                                          Mar09           28770
ies_-ies_-dbo_-topic                                                                                             Mar08           31651
ims_-ias_stage_-dbo_-topic                                                                                       Mar08           32109
tmi_-transactionalemail_-dbo_-topic                                                                              Mar08           32567
```

Code

```
def Kafka_mirror(envr,server):
        out = subprocess.Popen("/dsapps/admin/edp/scripts/edp-kafka-mirror-list all -e %s -h %s" % (envr,server), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
        return out

def mirrors_to_db(envr,server):

        for line in Kafka_mirror(envr,server):
                for i in line:
                        print(i)
```

Output of the script

```
k
a
f
k
a
-
m
i
r
r
o
r
```

Comment: Uh, you first iterate over the lines of the output and in the inner `for` you iterate over the characters of each line - just remove the inner `for` loop?

Comment: Yes, It is working, but it is take as one line, I am unable to read the specific details i wont from output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have Kafka, so I have used sample output string as a sample to execute the program, and also i have removed the arguments.

```
    def Kafka_mirror():
        #out = subprocess.Popen("/dsapps/admin/edp/scripts/edp-kafka-mirror-     
        #list all -e %s -h %s" % (envr,server), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  
        #shell=True).communicate()
        sampleOutput = """kafka-mirror              Running (9)  on frun4316                                                                 
        TIME            PID          Num.Streams


        ================================================================================    =======================================================================
        billing_-mainframe_-db2prod_-topic                                                                                   
        Mar08           565
        snap_-arep_-b2bowner_-topic,snap_-report_-b2bowner_-topic,snap_-arep_-isnapownera_-topic,snap_-report_-isnapownera_-topic Mar08           1024
        meds_-mlinterview_-hiss_-topic,meds_-mlinterview_-dbo_-topic                                                     Mar08           1902
        insite_-c1reppd_-insiteownera_-topic,insite_-cireprod_-insiteowner_-topic                                        Mar15           19386
        atlas_-clmprgg_-geico_claimcenter_-topic                                                                         Mar15           22222            2
        ecams_-ecamsdatastore_-ecamsmain_-topic                                                                          Mar09           28770
        ies_-ies_-dbo_-topic                                                                                             Mar08           31651
        ims_-ias_stage_-dbo_-topic                                                                                       Mar08           32109
        tmi_-transactionalemail_-dbo_-topic"""
        return sampleOutput


    def mirrors_to_db():
        for line in Kafka_mirror().split('\n'):
            print line

    mirrors_to_db()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But when i use split, it is giving me below error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./kafka_mirror.py", line 38, in <module>
    mirrors_to_db('test','frun5934')
  File "./kafka_mirror.py", line 16, in mirrors_to_db
    for line in Kafka_mirror(envr,server).split('\n'):
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Actually when we use subprocess.Popen("<commands>").communicate(), it gives tuple in the form of (stdout, stderr). So assign output of .communicate() to the two variables as: " result, exe_err = output.communicate()", and use result variable which will contain all command output. Refer link: https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/

Comment: Thanks Buddy, Seems like that is the issue, Now i can print one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd reference your comment to the first answer

> line 16, in mirrors_to_db for line in Kafka_mirror(envr,server).split('\n'): AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute

This clearly tells that your subprocess.Popen function returns the output as a list. 
So a single for loop should suffice:

```
def Kafka_mirror(envr,server):
    out = subprocess.Popen("/dsapps/admin/edp/scripts/edp-kafka-mirror-list all -e %s -h %s" % (envr,server), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
    return out
```

def mirrors_to_db(envr,server):

```
    for line in Kafka_mirror(envr,server):
          print line
```

This should work for you.

> Update:

```
import re
def Kafka_mirror(envr,server):
    out = subprocess.Popen("/dsapps/admin/edp/scripts/edp-kafka-mirror-list all -e %s -h %s" % (envr,server), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
    return out

def mirrors_to_db(envr,
    for line in Kafka_mirror(envr,server):
           temp_list = re.split(r'\t+', line)
           print temp_list[0]
           print temp_list[1]
           print temp_list[2]
           print temp_list[3]
```

this code should print all the 4 values that come on the command output.

Comment: Yes, This is work, but i cant read the data that i want from that out put, Such ans topic name server name PID etc.. bcz when i try to find frun5636  on that line and give condition for if it is found print that line and  else print some thing less. It say found and else part not working

Comment: Can you share your code of exactly what you trying to code ?

Comment: Thank you verry much for the support,Actually i need to get information from the out put, Such as mirror name and PID need to store to the variable then after to sqlite.

Comment: temp_list is the list that contains the values (in order) from the output. So temp_list[0] should be your mirror name, temp_list[3] should be your PID and so on. 
Glad i could help. Please upvote/chose as suggested answer if it worked for you